# Modifying HEVC HM reference software

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, video, hevc, h.265

I'm very new to the field of HEVC codec. I'm using the HM reference code version 10.1. My task is to make larger block size Dimensions up to 128x128. So, what I tried was in the configuration file I set the parameters

> MaxCUWidth
>
> MaxCUHeight

as 128 and 128 respectively while Depth is 5 and

> QuadtreeLog2MinSize= 2
>
> QuadtreeLog2MaxSize= 6

.

This ensures that the max CU size is limited to 128 x 128. However, the code crashes with the errors:

{

Error: Minimum CU width must be greater than minimum transform size

Error: Minimum CU Height must be greater than minimum transform size

Error: QuadtreeLog2MaxSize must be 5 or greater

}

My problem is I'm not able to figure out where & how the code needs to be changed so that it does not effect other parameters. Any Kind of help regarding the same will be really valuable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me its done now For HEVC

> HM version (10.1)

Needs to modify on only Depth increment of 1 while `CusizeWidth` and `CuSizeheight` must be equal to 128. For that purpose I had made changes in `log2Bliksize<=7` containing

> TComPattern.cpp

and made changes in `MAX_CU_DEPTH` in

> TComRom.h

After that i got Block sizes / CU (Dimensions) of 128x128.